# Use row data to be inserted into table and update current table Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel

I use record data from a table to reduce the entries that the user will make as it will be stored in another table, but after saving it must update the status of the current record to be 'Used'

the current row is in table called airfiles and will be inserted after adding sale amount into table called tickets

here is the airfiles schema code :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('airfiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('airl')->nullable();
        $table->string('num')->nullable();
        $table->date('date')->nullable();
        $table->string('pass')->nullable();
        $table->string('route')->nullable();
        $table->string('dot')->nullable();
        $table->string('dor')->nullable();
        $table->string('flynumt')->nullable();
        $table->string('flynumr')->nullable();
        $table->float('fare')->nullable();
        $table->float('tax')->nullable();
        $table->float('total')->nullable();
        $table->float('comm')->nullable();
        $table->float('net')->nullable();
        $table->string('rloc')->nullable();
        $table->string('son')->nullable();
        $table->string('acc')->nullable();
        $table->string('pcc')->nullable();
        $table->tinyInteger('progid')->default('1');
        $table->string('status')->nullable();
        $table->integer('segment')->nullable();
        $table->string('filename')->nullable();
        $table->float('k7')->nullable();
        $table->string('used')->nullable();
        $table->string('transfer')->nullable();
        $table->integer('ticket_id')->unsigned()->nullable();

        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();


    });
    Schema::table('airfiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('ticket_id')->references('id')->on('tickets')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

and here is the TicketController code:

```
public function store(Request $request, $id)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'date'=>'required',
        'tkt_no'=>'required',
        'sector'=>'required',
        'airline'=>'required',
        'supplier'=>'required',
        'fare'=>'required',
        'tax'=>'required',
        'total_tax'=>'required',
        'total_cost'=>'required',
        'k7'=>'required',
        'comm'=>'required',
        'profit'=>'required',
        'sale_price'=>'required',
        'sign'=>'required',
        'pax_name'=>'required',
        'mob'=>'required',
        'amount_arabic'=>'required',
        'amount_english'=>'required',
        'action_type'=>'required',
        'trans_type'=>'required',
        'payment_type'=>'required',

    ]);

    $ticket = new Ticket();
    $ticket->date = $request->get('date');
    $ticket->tkt_no = $request->get('tkt_no');
    $ticket->sector = $request->get('sector');
    $ticket->airline = $request->get('airline');
    $ticket->supplier = $request->get('supplier');
    $ticket->fare = $request->get('fare');
    $ticket->tax = $request->get('tax');
    $ticket->total_tax = $request->get('total_tax');
    $ticket->total_cost = $request->get('total_cost');
    $ticket->k7 = $request->get('k7');
    $ticket->comm = $request->get('comm');
    $ticket->profit = $request->get('profit');

    $ticket->sale_price = $request->get('sale_price');
    $ticket->sign = $request->get('sign');
    $ticket->branch =Auth::user()->branch_id;
    $ticket->pax_name = $request->get('pax_name');
    $ticket->mob = $request->get('mob');
    $ticket->amount_arabic = $request->get('amount_arabic');
    $ticket->amount_english = $request->get('amount_english');
    $ticket->action_type = $request->get('action_type');
    $ticket->trans_type = $request->get('trans_type');
    $ticket->payment_type = $request->get('payment_type');
    $ticket->post_flag = '0';
    $ticket->save();

    Airfile::find($id)->update(['used' => 'Used']);
    session()->flash('success',__('site.added_successfully'));
    return redirect()->route('$tickets.index');
}
```

here is the close blade code :

```
                    <div class="card-content collpase show">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form action="{{ route('tickets.store') }}" method="post">

                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                            {{ method_field('post') }}


                            <div class="row">


                                <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                                    <label>@lang('site.son')</label>

                                    @if(Auth::user()->shortsign == '--')
                                        <select class="select2-size-lg form-control border-primary"
                                                style="width: 100%;" name="sign">
                                            @foreach ($users as $user)
                                                <option
                                                    value="{{ $user->shortsign }}">{{ $user->shortsign }}</option>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </select>
                                    @else
                                        <select class="select2-size-lg form-control border-primary"
                                                style="width: 100%;" name="sign" readonly>
                                            <option
                                                value="{{ Auth::user()->shortsign }}">{{ Auth::user()->shortsign }}</option>
                                        </select>
                                    @endif

                                </div>


                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="pax_name">@lang('site.pax_name')</label>
                                        <div class="position-relative has-icon-left">
                                            <input type="text" id="pax_name" class="form-control"
                                                   name="pax_name"
                                                   value="{{ $airfiles->pass }}" readonly>
                                            <div class="form-control-position">
                                                <i class="la la-keyboard-o"></i>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="client">@lang('site.client')</label>
                                        <div class="position-relative has-icon-left">
                                            <input type="text" id="client" class="form-control"
                                                   name="client"
                                                   value="{{ $airfiles->pass }}">
                                            <div class="form-control-position">
                                                <i class="la la-keyboard-o"></i>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="mob">@lang('site.mob')</label>
                                        <div class="position-relative has-icon-left">
                                            <input type="text" id="mob" class="form-control"
                                                   name="mob"
                                                   value="{{ old('mob') }}">
                                            <div class="form-control-position">
                                                <i class="la la-keyboard-o"></i>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                                    <label>@lang('site.supplier')</label>
                                    <select class="form-control select2 status-type" style="width: 100%;"
                                            name="supplier"
                                            id="supplier">
                                        <option selected value="bsp">BSP</option>
                                        <option value="online">Online</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                                    <label>@lang('site.action_type')</label>
                                    <select class="form-control select2 status-type" style="width: 100%;"
                                            name="action_type"
                                            id="action_type">
                                        <option selected value="issue">@lang('site.issue')</option>
                                        <option value="reissue">@lang('site.reissue')</option>
                                        <option value="emd">@lang('site.emd')</option>
                                        <option value="refund">@lang('site.refund')</option>
                                        {{--                                            <option value="void_charge">@lang('site.void_charge')</option>--}}
                                    </select>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                                    <label>@lang('site.trans_type')</label>
                                    <select class="form-control select2 status-type" style="width: 100%;"
                                            name="trans_type"
                                            id="trans_type">
                                        <option selected value="domestic">@lang('site.domestic')</option>
                                        <option value="international">@lang('site.international')</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                                    <label>@lang('site.payment_type')</label>
                                    <select class="form-control select2 status-type" style="width: 100%;"
                                            name="payment_type"
                                            id="payment_type">
                                        <option selected value="cash">@lang('site.cash')</option>
                                        <option value="credit">@lang('site.credit')</option>
                                        <option value="advance">@lang('site.advance')</option>
                                        <option value="pending">@lang('site.pending')</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                                    <label>@lang('site.airline')</label>
                                    <select class="form-control select2 status-type" style="width: 100%;"
                                            name="airline"
                                            id="airline">
                                        @foreach ($airlines as $airline)
                                            <option value="{{ $airline->code }}">{{ $airline->code }}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="sale_price">@lang('site.sale_price')</label>
                                        <div class="position-relative has-icon-left">
                                            <input type="text" id="sale_price" class="form-control"
                                                   name="sale_price" placeholder="0"
                                                   onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"
                                                   {{--                                                       onblur="findTotal()"--}}
                                                   onkeyup="main ();eng_main();findTotal()"
                                                   value=" {{ old('sale_price') }}">
                                            <div class="form-control-position">
                                                <i class="la la-keyboard-o"></i>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="tkt_no">@lang('site.tkt_no')</label>
                                        <div class="position-relative has-icon-left">
                                            <input type="text" id="tkt_no" class="form-control"
                                                   name="tkt_no" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"

                                                   value="{{ $airfiles->num }}" readonly>
                                            <div class="form-control-position">
                                                <i class="la la-keyboard-o"></i>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="rloc">@lang('site.rloc')</label>
                                        <div class="position-relative has-icon-left">
                                            <input type="text" id="rloc" class="form-control"
                                                   name="rloc"
                                                   value="{{ $airfiles->rloc }}" readonly>
                                            <div class="form-control-position">
                                                <i class="la la-keyboard-o"></i>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="sector">@lang('site.sector')</label>
                                        <div class="position-relative has-icon-left">
                                            <input type="text" id="sector" class="form-control"
                                                   name="sector" placeholder="@lang('site.like') : HAS/JED JED/MAA"
                                                   value="{{ $airfiles->route }}" readonly>
                                            <div class="form-control-position">
                                                <i class="la la-keyboard-o"></i>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="fare">@lang('site.fare')</label>
                                        <div class="position-relative has-icon-left">
                                            <input type="text" id="fare" class="form-control "
                                                   onblur="findTotal()"
                                                   name="fare" placeholder="0"
                                                   {{--                                                       onkeyup="main ()"--}}
                                                   value="{{ $airfiles->fare }}" readonly>
                                            <div class="form-control-position">
                                                <i class="la la-keyboard-o"></i>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="tax">@lang('site.tax')</label>
                                        <div class="position-relative has-icon-left">
                                            <input type="text" id="tax" class="form-control"
                                                   name="tax" placeholder="0"
                                                   onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"
                                                   onblur="findTotal()"
                                                   {{--                                                       onkeyup="return sum(event)"--}}
                                                   value="{{ $airfiles->tax }}" readonly>
                                            <div class="form-control-position">
                                                <i class="la la-keyboard-o"></i>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="k7">@lang('site.k7')</label>
                                        <div class="position-relative has-icon-left">
                                            <input type="text" id="k7" class="form-control"
                                                   name="k7" placeholder="0"
                                                   onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"
                                                   onblur="findTotal()"
                                                   {{--                                                       onkeyup="return sum(event)"--}}
                                                   value="{{ $airfiles->k7 }}" readonly>
                                            <div class="form-control-position">
                                                <i class="la la-keyboard-o"></i>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="comm">@lang('site.comm')</label>
                                        <div class="position-relative has-icon-left">
                                            <input type="text" id="comm" class="form-control"
                                                   name="comm" placeholder="0"
                                                   onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"
                                                   onblur="findTotal()"
                                                   {{--                                                       onkeyup="return sum(event)"--}}
                                                   value="{{ $airfiles->comm }}" readonly>
                                            <div class="form-control-position">
                                                <i class="la la-keyboard-o"></i>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="profit">@lang('site.profit')</label>
                                        <div class="position-relative has-icon-left">
                                            <input type="number" id="profit" class="form-control"
                                                   name="profit" placeholder="0"
                                                   onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"
                                                   onblur="findTotal()"
                                                   {{--                                                       onkeyup="return sum(event)"--}}
                                                   value="{{ number_format(old('profit'), 2) }}" readonly>
                                            <div class="form-control-position">
                                                <i class="la la-keyboard-o"></i>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="total_tax">@lang('site.total_tax')</label>
                                        <div class="position-relative has-icon-left">
                                            <input type="text" id="total_tax" class="form-control"
                                                   name="total_tax" placeholder="0"
                                                   onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"
                                                   onkeyup="return sum(event)"
                                                   value="{{ old('total_tax') }}" readonly>
                                            <div class="form-control-position">
                                                <i class="la la-keyboard-o"></i>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="total_cost">@lang('site.total_cost')</label>
                                        <div class="position-relative has-icon-left">
                                            <input type="text" id="total_cost" class="form-control"
                                                   name="total_cost" placeholder="0"
                                                   onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"
                                                   onkeyup="return sum(event)"
                                                   value="{{ old('total_cost') }}" readonly>
                                            <div class="form-control-position">
                                                <i class="la la-keyboard-o"></i>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <label for="date">@lang('site.date')</label>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <input id="date" name="date" class="form-control datepicker" type="date"
                                               value="{{ $airfiles->date }}" readonly>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="amount_arabic">@lang('site.amount_arabic')</label>
                                        <div class="position-relative has-icon-left">
                                            <input type="text" id="amount_arabic" class="form-control"
                                                   name="amount_arabic"
                                                   onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"
                                                   onkeyup="return sum(event)"
                                                   value=" {{ old('amount_arabic') }}" readonly>
                                            <div class="form-control-position">
                                                <i class="la la-keyboard-o"></i>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="amount_english">@lang('site.amount_english')</label>
                                        <div class="position-relative has-icon-left">
                                            <input type="text" id="amount_english" class="form-control"
                                                   name="amount_english"
                                                   onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"
                                                   onkeyup="return sum(event)"
                                                   value=" {{ old('amount_english') }}" readonly>
                                            <div class="form-control-position">
                                                <i class="la la-keyboard-o"></i>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                            </div>


                            <div class="form-actions right">
                                <button id="slide-toast" type="submit"
                                        class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-min-width box-shadow-2 mr-1 mb-1"><i
                                        class="la la-check-square-o"></i> @lang('site.close')</button>
                            </div>

                        </form><!-- end of form -->


                    </div><!-- end of box -->
                </div>
```

here is the route code :

```
    //airfile routes
Route::resource('airfiles', 'AirfileController')->except(['show']);
//ticket routes
Route::resource('tickets', 'TicketController')->except(['show']);
```

the error i got is :

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR)
>   Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\TicketController::store(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected

any one can help ?

Comment: Please put your form url

Comment: i edited the post sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because this methods expects an ID and may be you did not pass id from route to this method. you can pass id to route like this:

```
{{ route('routeName', ['id' => 1]) }}
```

And make your route like this:

```
Route::get('appName/{id}', ControllerName@store)->name('routeName');
```

Comment: i have got same error after i make it like that

                            <form action="{{ route('tickets.store', $airfiles->id) }}" method="post">

                                {{ csrf_field() }}
                                {{ method_field('post') }}

Comment: you should pass id in square brackets like {{ route('tickets.store', ['id'=>$airfiles->id)] }} @MohamadSalama